# Django replace part of the string with another model object value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have model with TextField and stored value (a lot of text) in this field contain words which need to be replaced with appropriate content from another model, which is small image gallery. I would like to use this words as some kind of signals which will tell django template where to place this small gallery inside content. Second model (gallery) contain few 3-8 images so when user (from admin area) write word ie. `#gallery.first` there will be thumbnail loaded from the gallery named first.

```
class Foo(models.model):
    ...
    text = models.TextField()
    ...

class Gallery(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

On the first time I was think to split all words in the view `for word in foo.text:` and search/replace but because text field contain a lot of words maybe it is not good idea. But if I try to create custom tag and write in text field `{% mytag %}` it is not rendered as template tag. Is there another way to get this working?

Comment: I think it will be better to process text field in view and create dict that is passed to template to render appropriately.

Comment: You can use regex to replace the necessary content or just foo.text.replace(old_word, new_word)